ImageView not updating properly
I am trying to generate a pdf in Android Java and I'm doing that by inflating a card view and changing the image using Picasso. I am loading the image from Firebase Storage using getDownloadUrl(). But when I try to do it, the pdf doesn't show anything, even the placeholder. However, when I do it normally with some random image, it shows the placeholder first and then shows the image.
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(
                new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Picasso.get()
                                .load(uri)
                                .resize(100, 100)
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .into(picture);
                    }
                }
        );

This is my code to call it, picture is the ImageView I inflated. I have tried pre-fetching the image seperately too and it ends up showing the same pdf withoout placeholder as well, so I think it is some kind of closure issue but I dont know why it's happening. Any ideas why this is happening?
Edit: I accidentally put the wrong variable inside due to mixup when copying the code, it doesn't work with uri either :/

WHat is img?  Your onSuccess function passes in a URI uri, and you aren't using it at all.  It seems like you have your variables mixed up.

I'm unclear - are you expecting an ImageView to display a downloaded PDF?

You aren't using the URI object at all. How would you like to set the image to the TextView if you're not using the URI? Please respond using @AlexMamo

@AlexMamo Mb, I mixed up when I was copying and pasting the code since I was testing it using different methods

@DougStevenson I am writing the image to the downloaded PDF
